# Soundcloud API returns 401 error on server-side Python authentication

Tags: python, linux, oauth, soundcloud

Trying to authenticate in Python to test a registered app, as per "Authenticating without the SoundCloud Connect Screen":
http://developers.soundcloud.com/docs/api/guide#user-credentials

```
import soundcloud

# create client object with app and user credentials
client = soundcloud.Client(client_id='YOUR_CLIENT_ID',
                           client_secret='YOUR_CLIENT_SECRET',
                           username='YOUR_USERNAME',
                           password='YOUR_PASSWORD')
```

The `password='YOUR_PASSWORD'` line throws an error:

```
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/soundcloud/client.py", line 41, in __init__
    self._credentials_flow()
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/soundcloud/client.py", line 112, in _credentials_flow
    make_request('post', url, options))
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/soundcloud/resource.py", line 62, in wrapped_resource
    setattr(result, attr, getattr(response, attr))
AttributeError: 'Response' object has no attribute 'error'
```

If I wrap it in a `try:`, I get:

```
Error: 401 Client Error: None, Status Code: 401
```

I've triple-checked the client_id and client_secret, I can log in using the same credentials on the website, and I've tried both 'username' and 'username@email.com' formats in the code. Any ideas?

[Edit:] For the record, both 'username' and 'username@email.com' formats work.

Comment: Try downgrading `requests` to version 0.14.2. I suspect that `soundcloud` if b0rken for `requests` version 1.0.0 and up.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll have to downgrade your `requests` library to version 0.14.2.

The `soundcloud` API python library wraps the `requests.models.Response` object, and with the refactor made for version 1.0.0, the `.error` attribute was removed. `soundcloud` however still expects it to be there.

I recommend you use a virtualenv to install libraries. You could manually remove the `requests` library from that virtualenv, or use `pip` to downgrade it:

```
pip install -I requests==0.14.2
```

You may want to report this issue to the [soundcloud-python code project](https://github.com/soundcloud/soundcloud-python/issues) so that they can either fix their `setup.py` dependency or fix the library to work with `requests` 1.0.0 or newer.

Comment: Immediate and total success. Amazing. Bravo!